# How to have a line cut off at a certain point but split at the nearest space

Tags: java, for-loop, substring, java.util.scanner

I want the each line to split off after 20 characters have gone by, but I want it to split off at the nearest space so the sentence has only whole words.

Heres my code:

```
System.out.println("Please input a word: ");
            Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = stringScanner.nextLine();
            
            
            int numberOfCharacters = 20;
    
            for(int pos = numberOfCharacters; pos >= 0; pos --)
            {
                if(input.charAt(pos) == ' ')
                {
                    System.out.println(input.substring(0, pos)); 
                    System.out.println(input.substring(pos+1,21)); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the output I am getting and have no idea why:

Please input a word:

```
Hello there, I am doing some coding, I need some help
Hello there, I am
doi
Hello there, I
am doi
Hello there,
I am doi
Hello
there, I am doi
```

```
The output I want is:
Hello there, I am
doing some coding, 
I need some help
```

Than you for any help.

Comment: I suggest you split the line into words and then print these words until the sum of lengths exceeds your limit. You will need two nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you can take is:

```
str="some long string"
while (str can be safely split) {
   split off and print the left portion
   assign the right portion to str
}
print the remainder of str
```

If you're wanting to not alter the input and manage positions, it would be simpler to use two variables, a startPos and an endPos.

```
str="some long string"
startPos=0, endPos=0
while (startPos < str.length) {
    determine endPos
    print substring from startPos to endPos
    move startPos to endPos+1
}
```

Comment: I know that I am late in asking for clarification but what do you mean by  move startPos to endPos+1

Comment: Simply meant `startPos = endPos + 1;`

Comment: If your sentence is 50 characters, for example, your loop will determine a new endPos based on your new startPos + 20 + distance to next space (or to end of string, whichever comes first)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
String str = "What's in a name? That which we call a rose "
         + "By any other name would smell as sweet;";

List<String> list = splitLine(str, 20);
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
What's in a name?
That which we call
a rose By any other
name would smell as
sweet;
```

- allocate a `List` to hold the substrings
- loop until the line is `blank` or if the remaining segment is less than `size`
- now check the character for spaces starting at size less 1.
- Add that substring to the list and update the line to the next starting position.

```
public static List<String> splitLine(String line, int size) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!line.isBlank()) {
        int len = Math.min(line.length(), size);
        if (len < size) {
            list.add(line);
            break;
        }
        while (line.charAt(--len) != ' ') {
           if (len == 0) {
             throw new 
                 IllegalArgumentException("\nWord length exceeds size specification");
           }
        }
        list.add(line.substring(0, len));
        line = line.substring(len+1);
    }
    return list;
}
```